# How to launch Forza 7 from PC?

Tags: xbox-network, forza-motorsport-7

Sorry to seem dense. I purchased and installed Forza 7 on my PC.  Microsoft put a Forza 7 icon in the Windows 10 start menu.  Clicking it does nothing.  Dbl-clicking, nothing.  I opened the Xbox Console companion, Forza 7 shows up there, with "Play" button.  Clicking that does nothing.   Is there some trick to this?  Why does it have to be this challenging to simply launch a game?  This is my first X-box game on my PC, I play Steam games all the time with no issues.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @jimo3 and welcome to Arqade SE! Are you sure that you have placed a link to the actual .exe file of forza 7 on your start menu, or is it simply a shortcut to the icon? I have never dealt with xbox to PC games before so I don't want to post a full answer yet. #PCMR

Comment: Did you purchase the game from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: @Paul, the shortcut does not have any right-click "properites" like file location/target.  It has an option to go to app settings. Bizarre that the shorctut wouldn't be an actual...shortcut.

Comment: @Nolonar, yes I purchased it fully legally from the Microsoft store. I had actually had it working once--i initially just installed by default to my C: SSD drive, when I saw the size was 100 gig I de-installed (fully using the instructions) and put it on another hard drive, because I image my C: weekly and save the last 5 images for 'just in case', and that extra 100 gig over-ran the drive I save my backups to.  So it installed fine on the new drive--no errors, the icons "looked" the same, they just don't work.

Comment: It just gets worse. I found the .exe in my P:\WindowsApps (the other drive), and MS locked down all permissions...I may have overstepped by doing this but I changed owner to local admins and made sure all existing permissions cascaded.  Still dbl-clicking the .exe (or trying to randomly edit-in-notopad++ *any* file gives the error "Can't find the file specified".  It shows the exact correct path and I, System, TurstedInstaller, etc, all have rights, but it still won't do it. I now see the "Encrypted" box checked!  Jeez microsoft, paranoid much?

Comment: Sounds like the game's trying to access a file on C, even though it's installed on P. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to help... sorry.

Comment: I did another de-install/re-install and it worked on P: this time.  I did nothing different but the outcome was successful, so for once the 'definition of insanity' rule was broken...

Comment: @jimo3 glad to hear you got it resolved! Sometimes it’s just a matter of what’s open or what permissions you have at time of install or what remnants may have remained from a previous install. Whatever the case may be, race on!